# Capture MQ down event from Spring JMS

Tags: java, spring, jms, spring-jms, mq

Does Default Message Listener Container of Spring have any method like ErrorHandler where I can Capture MQ down Event.

I can get following logs from spring but need to report when MQ is down.

```
o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer  : Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination
o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer  : Successfully refreshed JMS Connection
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I solved my issue by overrding  **refreshConnectionUntilSuccessful** of **DefaultMessageListenerContainer** as below:

```
public class MessageListenerContainer extends DefaultMessageListenerContainer {

@Override protected void refreshConnectionUntilSuccessful() {
    super.refreshConnectionUntilSuccessful();
    // Your own implementation goes here like sending an email
    logger.error(MessageListenerContainer.class, new Exception("MQ CONNECTION LOST"));
}}
```